# extracting catching patterns from string in R

Tags: r, string, match, extract

I'm doing an R course and I need to comment on what's going on in the following code:

```
str_extract(tabels, "^[ei][0-9]{3}$")
```

What I think I know is that I'm matching in the string "tabels", when the first two letters are ei. Also the $ sign tells me that that I'm trying to match something in the end.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here. What is going on?

Best 
Frank

Comment: The pattern matches from the start of the string, then either `e` or `i`, then 3 digits 0-9 at the end of the string.

Comment: That was very useful, thanks! Just to be clear, it has to match 3 digits of numbers between 0 and 9 in the end?

Comment: That is correct, see these examples https://regex101.com/r/FZH2ck/1